# How to find and replace for an occurence of a string anywhere on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have only found code snippets that work when looking in a specific class or id for an occurrence of a string.

I want to search a whole page and replace each occurrence of a string (lets say "Bam" with "Boom") regardless of how many times or where it appears.

I have tried this, but the page just constantly loads:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('body').html($('body').html().replace('Boom','Bam'));   
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: `I have tried this, but the page just constantly loads` is that code inside the body tag that you're replacing?

Comment: Yes, the code is in the body tag.

Comment: Then that's the first problem you have to fix if you want to replace the html of the body.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a global regex.

```
$(function() {
    $('body').html($('body').html().replace(/Boom/g,'Bam'));   
});
```

"g" is the global parameter. See [RegExp on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Another common way to do this is as follows:

```
var regex = /Boom/g,
    html = $('body').replace(regex,'Bam');

$('body').html(html);
```

Additionally, if you would like to ignore the case of the capital **B** in **Boom**, you can utilize the "i" parameter:

```
/Boom/gi
```

This will select all occurrences of **Boom**, and all occurrences of **boom**.

Comment: Note however that this brute-force way of doing it will cause any javascript-bound events and data to be unbound and lost.

Comment: I believe this is because it then dynamically replaces the entire body of the HTML after the DOM has already loaded, correct?  So old event handlers wouldn't apply to the newly loaded HTML.

Comment: What if the OP were to use .text() instead?

Comment: Correct. And if this code is inside the body tag, it will constantly run over and over. :) If he were to use .text(), the same would happen, only, all html would be lost leaving just text.